# Object Detection from Image Classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification

Can I use a model used for Image Classification to do Object Detection? Already I spent too much time doing the image collection and distribute each class into it folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use your classification model as an initialized backbone for a detection model (e.g. Faster-RCNN) but it might not help that much compared to train your detector from scratch.
2. You will need to add detection layers (e.g. ROI pooling) to your backbone to perform detection.
3. While you can try unsupervised object detection, usually you will need extra labels such as object bounding-boxes to train your object detector.